# Process powershell.exe starts and eat up the memory

Tags: powershell

**Laptop brand**: EliteBook 8440p
**Operating System**: Windows 7
**Problem**: I find out that a process named powershell.exe runs several times every day and once it starts up it will eat up my memory, costs physical memory about 90%. Then my PC becomes very slow. It will stop itself after a few minutes. Please advise, thanks a lot...

Comment: vote to close, belongs on superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or some other tool to see what it is running ( command line ) and / or which process triggered it. It might be a scheduled task or something. If so, remove it if you think it is unintended.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help, I used Process Explorer to find out that command line and deleted it. But I am still confused that which service causes this command to start.